# Tkinter - Creating dynamic buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, audio-player, dynamic-variables

I'm trying to build a music player. For now it's really simple and I'm stuck while trying to make some sort of queue.

I decided that I want to make every song on list "clickable" that's going to call another function with its path as the argument. I've tried to create dynamic buttons that's going to create a new button every time I click on <kbd>Search</kbd> and failed many times trying different methods. For now I'm stuck on:

```
def searchmusic(self):
    self.newmusicpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title = "Szukajka", filetypes = (("mp3","*.mp3"),("all","*.*")))
    #self.playmusic(self.newmusicpath)
    self.music_dict["song" + str(self.music_on_list_number)] = self.newmusicpath
    print(self.music_dict)

    locals()['song{}partial'.format(self.music_on_list_number)] = print("TEST DONE")
    locals()['song{}'.format(self.music_on_list_number)] = tk.Button(canvas, text = self.newmusicpath, command = exec('song{}partial'.format(self.music_on_list_number)))

    exec('song{}.pack()'.format(self.music_on_list_number))
    self.music_on_list_number += 1
```

Sadly line `locals()['song{}partial'.format(self.music_on_list_number)] = print("TEST DONE")` is executing right after I search for new song instead of clicking that new song button.

Rest of code:

```
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
import os
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import functools

pygame.mixer.init()

class music:
    def __init__(self):
        self.music_playing  = False
        self.music_pause = False
        self.currently_playing_label = "Nyan Cat"
        self.currently_playing = r"C:/Users/Happy\Desktop/Raspbian python/nyan.mp3"
        self.music_dict = {}
        self.CurrentSongLabel = tk.Label(frame, text = "None", bg = 'green')
        self.CurrentSongLabel.pack()
        self.music_on_list_number = 0

    def volumecontrol(self, volumeslider):
        pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(int(volumeslider)/100)

        #Start/Pause button
    def playbutton(self):
        if self.music_playing == False:
            self.music_playing = True
            self.playmusic(self.currently_playing)
        elif self.music_pause == False:
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
            self.music_pause = True
        elif self.music_pause == True:
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
            self.music_pause = False

        #Music play
    def playmusic(self, pathtonewmusic):
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() != -1:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        self.currently_playing = pathtonewmusic
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.currently_playing)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        self.currentlyplayinglabel()

        #Label change
    def currentlyplayinglabel(self):
        if self.CurrentSongLabel:
            self.CurrentSongLabel.destroy()
        self.currently_playing_as_list = self.currently_playing.split("/")
        self.currently_playing_label = self.currently_playing_as_list[-1]
        self.CurrentSongLabel = tk.Label(frame, text = self.currently_playing_label, bg = 'green', fg = 'lightblue')
        self.CurrentSongLabel.pack()

        #Music search
    def searchmusic(self):
        self.newmusicpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title = "Szukajka", filetypes = (("mp3","*.mp3"),("all","*.*")))
        #self.playmusic(self.newmusicpath)
        self.music_dict["song" + str(self.music_on_list_number)] = self.newmusicpath
        print(self.music_dict)

        locals()['song{}partial'.format(self.music_on_list_number)] = print("TEST DONE")
        locals()['song{}'.format(self.music_on_list_number)] = tk.Button(canvas, text = self.newmusicpath, command = exec('song{}partial'.format(self.music_on_list_number)))

        exec('song{}.pack()'.format(self.music_on_list_number))
        self.music_on_list_number += 1

#Creating windows
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 100, bg = 'red')
canvas.grid(row = 5, columnspan = 3)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'green')
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4)
LabelPlayingCurrently = tk.Label(frame, text = "CURRENTLY PLAYING:", bg = 'green', fg = 'lightblue')
LabelPlayingCurrently.pack()

#Init music function
music_inited = music()

#Music control buttons
play = tk.Button(root, text = 'Play/Pause', fg='white', padx = 15, pady = 30, bg = "red", command = music_inited.playbutton)
play.grid(row = 3, column = 0, rowspan = 2)

nextsong = tk.Button(root, text = 'Nastepna', fg='white', bg = "red", pady = 10, padx = 6)
nextsong.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

previoussong = tk.Button(root, text = 'Poprzednia', fg='white', bg = "red", pady = 10)
previoussong.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

volume = tk.Scale(root, label = "VOLUME", from_ = 100, to = 0, command=music_inited.volumecontrol)
volume.set(5)
volume.grid(row = 3, column = 2, rowspan = 2)

#Music search button
searchbutton = tk.Button(root, text = 'Search', fg='white', bg = "red", command = music_inited.searchmusic)
searchbutton.grid(row = 8, column = 0, columnspan = 3)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Get rid of `exec...` and read up on [Python and Tkinter lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11005426/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
locals()['song{}partial'.format(self.music_on_list_number)] = print("TEST DONE")
```

will execute print(“TEST DONE”) and then assign None to a variable in locals()

Did you mean:

```
locals()['song{}partial'.format(self.music_on_list_number)] = lambda : print("TEST DONE")
```