# How do I iterating throw list of lables in TKinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I'm trying to create 18 by 18 grid of labels and make each label have an `Enter` and `Leave` event. But when I write the code it only creates an event for the last lable in the grid. What am I not getting here?

p.s.
Sorry if the code is messy, I'm only 1 month into learning Python

```
from tkinter import *
import string


root = Tk()


sequence_lst = list(string.ascii_letters)
execute = 0
num = 2

while execute < 3:
    for i in range(len(sequence_lst)):
        sequence_lst.append(sequence_lst[i]*num)
    execute += 1
    num += 1
sequence_lst = sequence_lst[:324]



position_x = 0
position_y = 0
square_lst = []
while position_x < 18:
    for i in range(18):
        if position_y < 18:
            square = Label(root, width=2, borderwidth=1, relief='solid')
            square.grid(row=position_x, column=position_y)
            position_y += 1
            square_lst.append(square)
        else:
            position_y = 0
            position_x += 1


for sequence in sequence_lst:
    sequence = square_lst[sequence_lst.index(sequence)]
    sequence.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: sequence.configure(bg='blue'))
    sequence.bind('<Leave>', lambda event: sequence.configure(bg='white'))        


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read [Python and Tkinter lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11005426/7414759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your bindings to refer to the widget associated with the event, using `event.widget`:

```
sequence.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: event.widget.configure(bg='blue'))
sequence.bind('<Leave>', lambda event: event.widget.configure(bg='white'))
```